# Show by the definition, that the function is continuous(multivariable calculus)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

$f(x,y):=6x-xy$ in the point of $(-2,1)$ Do I have to use the definiton of the continuity of functions with two variables?

Comment: It is well known that polynomials are continuous...

Comment: Yes if that what they asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if they ask you to use the definition you would use the definition. Note you can show that the partials at the point $(-2,1)$ exist *and* the partial derivatives are continuous. This establishes continuity at a point. This generalizes from $\mathbb{R}^2$ very simply to $\mathbb{R}^n$